# How I can use font awesome icon in the placeholder while I am using **React js**?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, placeholder

In HTML , it is quite easy to use font awesome icons in  placeholder by using the **unicode** in placeholder and changing the font-style to 'Font Awesome 5 Free' . As , React uses JSX not html , I am facing problem to use the font awesome in placeholder. In this case, how can I use font awesome in Placeholder?
Or there are any alternative icons which I can use in placeholder which will be more efficient?